# How to remove date from datetime object

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a method that converts a string to a datetime object using `strptime("%I:%M %p")`, I only want the hours in 24 and minutes without any dates, because I will get the difference between this time and another time. The problem is that when I try to get the difference with `total_seconds()`, it gets difference in negative because the date in the strptime is "1900-01-01". Does any one have any ideas how to solve this?

My Code:

```
fTime = datetime.strptime(time, "%I:%M %p")
if 0 < (fTime - datetime.now()).total_seconds() <= 3600:
   return True
```

Comment: I want a way to remove the date from the fTime so that the difference is in positive

Comment: yes, I am @MadPhysicist. This is what I am doing

Comment: I want to get the difference between these two times and check if it is less than or equal to one hour, pretty simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247021/discussion-between-omar-yacop-and-mad-physicist).

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the date from today, or set fTime to today's date?

Comment: yes, this is what I want

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's a long night for me and I'm not thinking straight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take one of two approaches: strip the date out of `now`, or add the current date to `fTime`. The first approach makes little sense, since you can't compare [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) objects like that anyway.

To convert `fTime` to a proper `datetime`, [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) it with [`date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today):

```
fDate = datetime.combine(date.today(), fTime.time())
return 0 < (fDate - datetime.now()).total_seconds() <= 3600
```

Alternatively, you can [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) the date portion:

```
today = date.today()
fDate = fTime.replace(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day)
```

Personally, I would go with `combine` because it's less awkward code.